# In a database, what is the best way of validating uniqueness if uniqueness depends on multiple columns?

Tags: database, database-design

For example, I deem that a record is unique based on the name and address columns. Do I just do my searches using both columns (or possibly more) or do I create a separate column (and indexed) with the string joined values of name and address? 
For example:

```
name: "foo"
address: "NY"
unique_key: "foo:NY"
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to "deem" that a record is unique.  But, you can have the database enforce the uniqueness with a unique constraint or index:

```
alter table t add constraint unq_t_name_address unique(name, address)
```